# Evaluating the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^3}.$$

I tried integration by partial fraction. My work is below:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}.$$

**It seems that the result would go to infinity**. But the answer is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}$.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The whole answer together works out, perhaps you could compute the integral using a limit instead?

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^n}~=~\frac\pi n\cdot\csc\bigg(\frac\pi n\bigg)$

Comment: 1) $t = {1 \over 1 + x^{3}}$ with Beta function or 2) $x^{3} \mapsto x$ with Ramanujan MT.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. You may first integrate over the finite set $[0,M]$ then let $M \to \infty$:
$$\int_{0}^M\frac{dx}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^M\frac{1}{x+1}\:dx+\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^M\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}\:dx,$$ you will see that the $\log$ terms cancel.

---

*Edit*. Let $M>0$. We have $$\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^M\frac{1}{x+1}\:dx=\frac{1}{3}\log (M+1)$$
$$\frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^M\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}\:dx=-\frac{1}{6}\log (M^2-M+1)-\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2 M-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}.$$

You may observe that, as $M \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{3}\log (M+1)-\frac{1}{6}\log (M^2-M+1)=\frac{1}{6}\log \left(\frac{1+2/M+1/M^2}{1-1/M+1/M^2} \right) \to 0.
$$

Comment: How did you get the integral of (2-x)/(x^2-x+1) is equal to that stuff? Thank you!

Comment: @yueeee You may first write the integrand as:$$
\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}=-\frac12\frac{(x^2-x+1)'}{x^2-x+1}+\frac32\frac1{(x-1/2)^2 +3/4}
$$ then integrate each term.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^3}dx&\overset{x\to\frac1x}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^3}dx
= \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}dx\\
& = \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx
=\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt3}\bigg|_0^\infty=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}
\end{align}